# how to read a static file from url in javascript to create an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, csv, url

I searched but I don't find, I am coding a simulator and I want to do the calculus using javascript, the simulator takes 2 kind of entries. The first entries are given by user, this part is done. The second part is a lot of coefficient which are stored in csv/tsv file, the file is uploaded on the server. And I am not able to read this file, I found a lot of code on how to convert csv to array and I think that I will be able to do it alone. For now I am doing step by step so I just want to read the csv file to put it inside a table, when I use the code shown it works if I use an < input type="file" > but I am not able to make it works with a static url. Can You help me?

```
function myprocessFile() 
{   

    var fileSize = 0;
    var theFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];    

    document.getElementById("toto").innerHTML = blob;    
    if (theFile) 
    {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var headerLine = "";
        var myReader = new FileReader();
        myReader.onload = function(e) 
        {   
            // CREATE TABLE
        }
        myReader.readAsText(theFile);  
    }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Comment: I m totally noob in js, it s my first code like this. I know nothing about AJAX can You tell me more? or can You give me a link related to my pb and I will search myself in it? Thank You

Comment: Amsterdamsche Football Club Ajax xD

Comment: Thank You I manage to do it using ajax

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `fetch` API :

```js
fetch('url/to/your/csv/file')
.then(function(response) {
  return response.text()
})
.then(function(csv) {
  // convert your csv to an array
});
```

Comment: Thank You I am gonna try this, in this case the variable csv is a text? is myReader.readAsText(theFile); can work for it or I should parse the csv differently?